# Is there some way to use tqdm with simpy.Environment.run()?

Tags: python, tqdm, simpy

Hello I am just wondering if there exist some magic way, of using tqdm for predicting how long will
it take for the entire simpy simulation of an Environment.

I tried doing something like:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

tqdm(env.run(until=100))
```

But with no effect. Anyone knows whether it is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I am not that familiar with tqdm, but I think you need to use it to wrap a iterator and `env.run(until=100)`is not a iterator.  However, you can run a sim in steps where you keep increasing the until param.  Here is a example

```
"""
quick test of tqdm progress bar with a sim

Programer Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy
from tqdm import tqdm 
import time


def task(env):
    """
    dummy task to sim
    """
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(1)

# create sim
env = simpy.RealtimeEnvironment(factor=.1)
env.process(task(env))

# run sim in steps
for t in tqdm(range(10,101,5)):
    env.run(until=t)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Michael is right about the usage of `run(until=...)` in the for loop. It works like a charm.

It is always a bit tricky working with range, so here is a more verbose example to make sure that the last value for `t` is equal to `total_events`. I hope the variables `total_events` and `step_size` help.
The start value for `trange` is `step_size` itself, since `0` is not a valid input for `run(until=...)`.

The convenient function `trange` from `tqdm` is used as well.

```py
import simpy
from tqdm import trange


def process(env):
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(5)

env = simpy.Environment()

env.process(process(env))

total_events = 100
step_size = 10

for t in trange(step_size, total_events+step_size, step_size):
    env.run(until=t)
```